# Upgrade my Lenovo's x200s to an SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, lenovo-laptop

I'm currently using a Lenovo x200s laptop, which I am very happy with.  I have Linux installed, and I would like to upgrade the existing HD to use a solid state drive.  I was wondering how I could find a good compatible SSD for this laptop.

Is there some standard size/configuration HD that this laptop supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any standard SATA SSD in the same form factor (I believe that laptop uses a 2.5" hard drive) should work fine.  You could also use a 1.8" if you get a caddy.

More generally, there are next to no laptops on the market that aren't using standard drives.  *Any drive that is the same connection bus and form factor should work in place of any removable* (that is, not soldered or otherwise fixed in place) *hard drive on any laptop* except in the extremely unlikely event the laptop is BIOS locked to only accept certain ones.

Comment: Would SATA II or III also work with this laptop?

Comment: @oneself - It's SATA II.  Nobody's shipped laptops with SATA I for years (maybe some cheap netbooks are using it) and I don't think anybody's shipping SATA III.  That said, all SATA is supposed to be both backwards and forwards compatible - SATA is SATA.

Comment: Agree - I've changed the HDD of my X200s to an intel Postville SSD, and it runs nicely!